# Yii CGrid View view all after search

Tags: search, view, yii, grid, cgridview

I need some help, I've been figuring this for almost an hour and still can't find a way to fix this.

I have a search form to filter data from my CGridView, and I also need a button to view all the records after I finish using search, but I can't figure how to do it. Here's my code for jquery refresh button:

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('initRefresh',<<<JS
$('#refresh-button').on('click',function() {
   $('#app-asset-categories-grid').yiiGridView('update');
    return false;
});
JS
,CClientScript::POS_READY);
```

Here's my code for jquery search form:

```
Yii::app()->clientScript->registerScript('search', "
$('.search-button').click(function(){
    $('.search-form').toggle();
    return false;
});
$('.search-form form').submit(function(){
    $('#app-asset-categories-grid').yiiGridView('update', {
        data: $(this).serialize()
    });
    return false;
    });
");
```

And finally, my grid:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'id'=>'app-asset-categories-grid',
    'columns' => array(
        'category_id',
        'label',
        'description',
        'add_date',
        'modification_date',
        array(
            'name'=>'Status',
            'filter'=>array('1'=>'Active', '0'=>'Inactive'),
            'value'=>'($data->status=="1")?"Active":"Inactive"'
        ),
        array(
            'name'=>'Deletion Status',
            'filter'=>array('1'=>'Deactivate','0'=>'Active'),
            'value'=>'($data->deletion_status=="1")?"Deactivated":"Activated"'
        ),
        array(
            'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
        ),
    ),
));
```

I just wanted a refresh button to display all the data again after I use my search form. I need your help guys, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle update action in model and set `pagination` parameter false. An example how to do it:

Add hidden field in search form `_search.php`

```
<?php echo CHtml::hiddenField('show_all', 0, array("id"=>"show_all")); ?>
```

Then handle it in model's `search()` function (your grid uses it to get data)
like this:

```
    $criteria=new CDbCriteria;

    // some criterias

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria'=>$criteria,
        'pagination' => (isset($_GET["show_all"]) && $_GET["show_all"])?false:array(), // add this line
    ));
```

Then set **update** hidden field when you need it.

```
$('#refresh-button').on('click',function() {
   $('#show_all').val(1); // set it to show all
   $('#app-asset-categories-grid').yiiGridView('update');
   $('#show_all').val(0); // set to 0 for searching with pagination
    return false;
});
```

Thats it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. hmm, I haven't tried your code yet, but upon reading your given code, it looks like that it just disables the pagination feature which is not really what I'm asking. hmm, I'm asking how to refresh/reload the table (that will display all the values) after I use search, like a reset button to view all again the data. I appreciate your answer, thank you.

Comment: Hi, I have edited answer. The main purpose is to turn off pagination when you want to show all rows. But keep it when you search.

Comment: what I really need is a button/link that can clear filter and advanced search results and display all the data again.